# Stored procedure not returning correct result

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema_name.CHECKS
IS
   tbl_name        VARCHAR2 (50);
   constraint_nm   VARCHAR2 (100);
   CURSOR cur_constraint
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT table_name, constraint_name
        FROM all_constraints
       WHERE     constraint_type = 'R'
             AND STATUS = 'ENABLED'
             AND R_OWNER = 'owner1'
             AND r_constraint_name = 'constraint1';
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Constraint Name');
   OPEN cur_constraint;
   LOOP
      FETCH cur_constraint
      INTO tbl_name, constraint_nm;
      EXIT WHEN cur_constraint%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (constraint_nm||'~~'||tbl_name);
   END LOOP;
   close cur_constraint;
END CHECKS;
```

And I execute this procedure by

```
set serveroutput on

BEGIN
   schema_name.CHECKS ();
END;
```

And the output I get is

```
Procedure created.
Constraint Name
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It's not returning any result but ideally it should be returning a row (the select query used to define the cursor will return a row).

When I execute the above code as a PL/SQL Block like this

```
DECLARE
   tbl_name        VARCHAR2 (50);
   constraint_nm   VARCHAR2 (100);
   CURSOR cur_constraint
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT table_name, constraint_name
        FROM all_constraints
       WHERE     constraint_type = 'R'
             AND STATUS = 'ENABLED'
             AND R_OWNER = 'owner1'
             AND r_constraint_name = 'constraint1';
BEGIN
   FOR i IN cur_constraint
   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN cur_constraint%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.constraint_name||' is in '||i.table_name);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

It is returning one row as expected.

Please help me understand why it is behaving strange when the logic is same except the way I execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALL_CONSTRAINTS is a bit like a mirror. Every user will see something different in there based on grants to that user. When executed as a DEFINE RIGHTS stored procedure it shows only what the owner of the procedure can see as a result of privileges granted directly to the owner (not through a role).

When executed as an anonymous block, it will show what the running user can see as a result of privileges granted to the user directly OR through a currently active role.

An invoker rights stored procedure (google AUTHID CURRENT_USER) will show what the invoking user can see as a result of grants to the user directly or through a currently active role.

Answer (score 8):

I imagine this is because your schema has access to some 'owner1' schema objects only via a role and not granted directly.  Roles are not taken into account by stored procedures.  See [this AskTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319) for more details.

As Gary Myers says, you can change the procedure to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema_name.CHECKS
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
...
```

and it will then show constraints that the user running it can see.

Comment: I compile this stored procedure in a schema named 'schema_name'. 'owner1' is there only in the select query which gets data from 'all_constraints' table. I feel your answer is valid if i select the data from 'owner1' schema objects. Or do I need to get select access granted to 'schema_name' for 'all_constraints' table? As of now 'all_constraints' is having 'select' access to 'PUBLIC'.

Comment: It's not about your access to the ALL_CONSTRAINTS view; it is that the ALL_CONSTRAINTS view only shows you constraints on tables to which you have access.